# Extract records for 1 Week Time interval and Them start the next timer when the new week starts

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the query given below to extract the records for 1 Week Time interval.

```
 mysql_query("SELECT t1.username, SUM(t2.points) AS total 
    FROM actcontest t2 JOIN user t1 ON t1.userid = t2.userid WHERE t2.date
    BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND CURDATE()  GROUP BY t1.username ORDER BY 
    total DESC LIMIT 20");
```

Once the records are fetched I am using the different query to award bonuses to the top 3 users.

This works fine.

Problem:
Once bonus has been awarded to the last week, top 3 members, new dates shall start from the new week starting dates, where last week ended.

suppose: we started the timer on date: [dd/mm/yy] 
Week 1 = {01-01-2010  to 07/01/2010} 
Week 2 = {07-01-2010  to 14/01/2010} 
Week 3 = {14-01-2010  to 21/01/2010} 
Week 4 = {21-01-2010  to 28/01/2010}

Can you please help me in building this logic for my script.
I am using php and Mysql.

What I want to Do:
One i have awarded bonus to week one winners. I want timer to start fetching the members for the next week only, It should not include the previous dates .

I hope i clarified the question.

Comment: I have read your question 5 times, and I still don't understand the problem, do you want a way to increase the week or what do you want?

Comment: @Naruto, Would you like to comment on the question, I just need to build the logic

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this:

```
SET @weekNo := 4;
SET @dateStart := '2014-01-01';

SELECT ADDDATE(CONCAT(@dateStart, ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 7*(@weekNo-1) DAY),
    ADDDATE(CONCAT(@dateStart, ' 23:59:59'), INTERVAL 7*@weekNo-1 DAY);
```

You can check the above script in sql. You can change the 2 variables at the top: `@weekNo` is the week you need to compute the date interval since the start date. And the `@dateStart` is the date the timer started.

In your php code you can compute the date by replacing the dateStart and weekNo with php variables.

Comment: I did not get your idea,,, values are stored in the table using NOW(), This will be automatic process, every week all the records will reset and new timer will start each week ... would you please elaborate your idea –

Answer (score 0):

```
select field1,field2     
from table_name     
where date_sub( field_date , INTERVAL 7 day) <= now()
```

see this you will get hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358240/show-data-from-the-last-7-days/26358454#26358454